# How to extend service collection of application project to web api in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I create new ASP.NET Core 6 solution for a Web API with onion architecture, I just found it, in .NET 6, there is change about dependency injection.

This is my solution structure:

```
Solution
|- Application
|- Domain
|- Infrastructure
|- API
```

In `Application` project, I create this code for dependency injection:

```cs
namespace Application
{
    public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static void AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

After that I added `Application` project as dependency in application.

In previous versions of .NET Core, I can add this to `Startup.cs` like this `services.AddApplication();`, but in new .NET 6, I can not find `Startup.cs` and when I google it, .NET 6 has a different way to use dependency injection.

I already try add code in `Program.cs`

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddApplication();  <--- this one

builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

but it got error

> IServiceCollection does not contain AddApplication()

Please help me how to add dependency collection in .NET 6 properly.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine. Are you sure you added the Project Reference and `using`  correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Application as project reference to your Api project and it should resolve itself. And in using statements add `using Application;`

Comment: Thanks it works, and dont forget to rebuild solution first, before add using application